# Iterative loop of files in folder with puppet

Tags: ruby, puppet

I have a set of files in a folder. I would like to pass an array of the files in a folder to some function. I saw the following example

```
$files= ["C:/dir/file1", "C:/dir/file2", "C:/dir/file3",
         "C:/dir/file4", "C:/dir/file5"]

# function call with lambda:
$binaries.each |String $binary| {
  file {"/usr/bin/$binary":
    ensure => file,
  }
}
```

but instead of declaring files manually, can I read all the files from a directory and pass it to some function?

Comment: You can only do this with a custom fact. Are you ok with that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Dir`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Dir.html) to fetch all files using some pattern. For example:

```
[1] pry(main)> Dir["/Users/smefju/tmp/*"]
=> ["/Users/smefju/tmp/a.rb",
 "/Users/smefju/tmp/asd",
 "/Users/smefju/tmp/bm.rb",
 "/Users/smefju/tmp/cert",
 "/Users/smefju/tmp/gc",
 "/Users/smefju/tmp/qq"]
```

Comment: can we convert the above snippet to puppet @smefu

Comment: @Dev not sure about what you are asking now. To replace hardcoded array with dynamic values based on the directory content you can use `Dir` with a proper pattern and assign it directly to the `$files`. Just keep in mind that you have `$files` and `$binaries` in the code snippet (not sure it it was intended).

Comment: @StephenKing yes I want to ... Thanks. I don't have problem in declaring files manually in array but I'm checking is there anyway to loop files in directory via puppet

Comment: Puppet uses Ruby, so stop saying "in puppet". Do it in Ruby.